# Visual Studio Tools for AI - Variable Explorer not loading

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

Installed VS Tools for AI and tried to run a python deep learning script.
The script runs well on the Anaconda Interactive provided by the IDE. Problem is with the 'Variable Explorer'. It shows an error saying "Error retrieving environment list".

The Default python environment is set to Anaconda 4.4.0.

Any solution to get the prevailing variables in the executing script through the explorer?

[image]

Comment: That looks like R Tools' variable explorer not Python Tools, as far as I know Python does not have variable explorer in VS yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The comment from Jespar is correct, so promoting it to an answer.)

That Variable Explorer belongs to R tools, so it will only work when you are using R.

There is currently no variable explorer for Python in Visual Studio, so this will not work. The two options to inspect variables are to debug a script (set a breakpoint and use the Watch/Locals windows), or use the interactive window (and the normal Jupyter-style commands, if you've enabled "IPython interactive mode" from the Python Environments window).